# Caching results of Maps API call to reduce volume in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a public form which incudes a place name, which I'm using the Places API to get the Place ID, to then do another call to look up an address. I need to optimize the volume of API calls so I'm trying to add caching so that Sheets doesn't re-call the two APIs unnecessarily.

For some reason I can't get the caching to work, either it errors or I get "object object" as the response.

```
function locId(text) {
  var text = cache.get(cacheLocId);
  if (cacheLocId === null) {
    var API_KEY = 'XYZXYZXYZ';
    var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
    var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY;
    if (text == null) {
      console. log("I QUIT!")
      return;
      }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  }
  cache.put(cacheLocId, placeId)
  console. log(text)
  console. log(placeId)
  return placeId.candidates[0].place_id;
}
```

Comment: Your `cache` is undefined variable. Either fix it in your code or post minimal reproducible example. For now I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Need to know how your function is called and what the parameters are and as @Kos has said you can't have any undefined variables in a [mcve].  Also In my case I will not follow links to a google account since it exposes our email address and sometimes the links are hard to remove.  So try sheet images and data tables.  Or debug yourself.

Comment: @Cooper the data flow looks like this…

- Public user fills out form with a place name (e.g. College Park Hyundai)
- Form saves to a Google Sheet in say, A2
- Formula in other sheet in same document "=if(A2="","",locId(A2))"
- Function from original post is called to run

I can get the basic function to get the place ID from the Google API, but I'm trying to cache it since the way Google forms populate, I end up re-calling the same location over and over. So caching will mitigate to some extent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are overwriting the function argument and using cache keys and values the wrong way around. Try this pattern:

```
function locId(text) {
  if (!text || typeof text !== 'string') {
    return null;
  }
  const cache = CacheService.getDocumentCache();
  const cached = cache.get(text);
  if (cached) {
    return cached;
  }
  const API_KEY = 'XYZXYZXYZ';
  const baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  const queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  const placeId = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).candidates[0].place_id;
  cache.put(text, placeId);
  return placeId;
}
```

Comment: Yea I continued fiddling and was getting that text,placeId was the right order but what I still wasn't getting was this bit: `if (cached) {
    return cached;` Thanks very much!

Comment: See [if...else  at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).